# VBA code to crack a two character password

Tags: excel, vba, loops, passwords, brute-force

trying to crack a two character password

```
Sub BruteForce()

        Dim pw As String
        Dim i As Integer

        Do
            ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Login").Cells(4, 7).ClearContents
            For i = 1 To 2
                If i Mod 2 = 0 Then
                    pw = pw & Int((9 - 0 + 1) * Rnd + 0)
                Else
                    pw = pw & Chr(Int((90 - 65 + 1) * Rnd + 65))
                End If
            Next i
            ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Login").Cells(4, 7).Value = pw
            If ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Login").Cells(5, 7).Value <> "NO" Then
                Exit Do
            End If
        Loop

    End Sub
```

The code runs into an infinite loop and I am not sure how to fix

Comment: There probably is no sheet named "Login" in your workbook, the workbook containing this code. The code works fine on my end.

Comment: here is what my workbook looks like https://gyazo.com/8ba9e1bf083793188f280faf1828625d

Comment: I no longer experience the error, however it now runs into an infinite loop

Comment: The loop is 'infinite', because there is no condition on the `do ..... loop`. Also it takes very long time if you pick random password (`Rnd`) to check, and you do not keep track of which passwords you already used (The chance of retesting an already failed password increases every time)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Less complex to use a nested loop:

```
Sub BruteForce()

    Dim i As long, n As Long

    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Login")
        For i = 0 To 9
        For n = 1 to 26
            .Cells(4, 7).Value = Chr(64+n) & i
            DoEvents   
            If .Cells(5, 7).Value <> "NO" Then Exit Sub
        Next n
        Next i
    End With

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub BruteForce()

Dim pw As String
Dim i As Integer

Do
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Login").Cells(4, 7).ClearContents
    pw = ""
    For i = 1 To 2
        If i Mod 2 = 0 Then
            pw = pw & Int((9 - 0 + 1) * Rnd + 0)
        Else
            pw = pw & Chr(Int((90 - 65 + 1) * Rnd + 65))
        End If
    Next i
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Login").Cells(4, 7).Value = pw
    If ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Login").Cells(5, 7).Value <> "NO" Then
        Exit Do
    End If
Loop
```

End Sub

solved